# Detecting the end of a method chaining

Tags: javascript, timer

I've been through a lot of posts over the web(and in SO) saying that it is not possible. However, I did the following code:

```js
var a = {
 _sum: 0,
 _timer: null,
 _resetTimer: function() {
  if (this._timer) {
   window.clearTimeout(this._timer);
  }

  this._timer = window.setTimeout(this._endChain.bind(this), 0);
 },
 _endChain: function() {
  console.log(this._sum);
 },

 A: function() {
  this._resetTimer();
  this._sum+= 1;
  return this;
 },
 B: function() {
  this._resetTimer();
  this._sum+= 2;
  return this;
 }
};

a.A().B().B().A();
```

[<sub>Demo in JsFiddle</sub>](https://jsfiddle.net/prmgsn9y/)

I want to know how problematic this can be, if this is not encouraged to be used.

**Edit**:

A negative point is: if you need anything that would be processed by `_endChain` you could not use `return`, only with a promise or another timeout outside the whole chain. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/prmgsn9y/1/).

Answer (score 3):

It's not problematic in the sense that `_endChain` will always be called after the whole chain. In fact you could simplify the code by only creating the timer once:

```js
var a = {
  _timer: null,
  _resetTimer: function() {
    if (!this._timer)
     this._timer = window.setTimeout(this._endChain.bind(this), 0);
  },
```

But the problem will come with code that follows for example:

```
a.A().B().B().A();
DoMoreStuff();
```

Most developers would be surprised to find that the first call has not completed. I think the better solution would be to implement an `end` method which is what many libraries do:

```
let result = a.A().B().B().A().end();
DoMoreStuff();
```

Or a promise like method:

```
a.A().B().B().A().then( function(result) {
  DoMoreStuff();
});
```

Comment: So it could work in case of a lone method which the rest of the code doesn't depends on.